# Java.io.ioexception Stream Closed

Tags: java, android, download

I'm developing an android app using augmented reallity with metaio. Well, In my app i've to download some images from an url. But when I do it, I've got an error and it only gets a part of the file.

I've this:

```
 04-30 14:43:25.625: W/ExternalStorage(14181): Error writing /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.augmentedwine/files/Download/LOL.jpg
 04-30 14:43:25.625: W/ExternalStorage(14181): java.io.IOException: stream closed
 04-30 14:43:25.625: W/ExternalStorage(14181):  at libcore.net.http.AbstractHttpInputStream.checkNotClosed(AbstractHttpInputStream.java:68)
 04-30 14:43:25.625: W/ExternalStorage(14181):  at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthInputStream.available(FixedLengthInputStream.java:59)
 04-30 14:43:25.625: W/ExternalStorage(14181):  at com.augmentedwine.view.ARActivity.createExternalStoragePrivatePicture(ARActivity.java:325)
 04-30 14:43:25.625: W/ExternalStorage(14181):  at com.augmentedwine.view.ARActivity$1.run(ARActivity.java:254)
 04-30 14:43:25.625: W/ExternalStorage(14181):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1434)
 04-30 14:43:25.625: W/ExternalStorage(14181):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1217)
```

In this function:

```
 void createExternalStoragePrivatePicture(String url) throws MalformedURLException,      IOException {

    File path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File file = new File(path, "LOL.jpg");

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();


    try {

        InputStream is = input;
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(data);
        os.write(data);
        is.close();
        os.close();

        Log.d("Size", "Tamanho " + is.available());


        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Unable to create file, likely because external storage is
        // not currently mounted.
        Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
    }
}
```

Can you help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you add the necessary permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: yup.


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: What about <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> ?

Comment: I've that too.
This is weird because I can download some "chunks" of the image.

Comment: Try this code:
`DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(is);
byte[] data = is.readUTF().getBytes();`
I use this one in my app and it works. Maybe it will help.

Comment: Immediately before `byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];`, can you do `System.out.println("Size in bytes: " + is.available());` and let us know what is output.

Comment: By the way you should always close your resources in a `finnaly`-block      or if you are using java7 the **try-with-resources Statement**. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: *Do not use* `is.available()`! You cannot trust it ;)

Comment: From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available() : **"It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream."**

Comment: When i do sysout of is.available() the output is

04-30 16:06:22.584: I/System.out(20528): Size in bytes: 12315

but the originial file has 19114 bytes

Comment: @Luis `is.available` does not do what you expect. See my comments above.

Comment: @Fildor I saw that. Thanks :D